# Change Lightswitch internal database to external

Tags: database-connection, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have been developing an application in Visual Studio Lightswitch (Silverlight client in VS2010 SP1 if it makes any difference), and so far have done all the database development in the Lightswitch designer.

I now want to use an external database, but don't want to recreate the whole app, or even just the screens. I have scripted the database, and have created a copy in SQL Server, but can't find out how to get Lightswitch to use this external database without starting the whole thing again.

Is there a simple way to change the connection string so that I can carry on from where I am, but have Lightswitch point at the external database instead of the internal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a very difficult thing to do. Super Lightswitch-hacker David Baker saw a post I'd made on the subject in the MSDN Lightswitch forum, and kindly offered to have a go at it for me. It took him several goes, but we got there in the end.

I wouldn't recommend this to anyone. I would strongly recommend using an external database right from the start. I can't see much benefit from using the internal one, and if you ever need more control over it, or want to switch to an external one, you've got major problems.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You must publish your project in order to create a new SQL database , publishing your project will create DB scripts for your new DB , don't use the internal LS DB to create script for your new DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that wasn't actually my question