# How to change connection _IntrinsicData to external sql in lightswitch?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've used [Lightswitch with MVC](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3281/An-HTML-MVC-LightSwitch-Security-Administration.aspx)

This example is used _IntrinsicData(.mdf) application. But I've asp.net membership database in my sql server can i used in this application?

But I don't know how to change connection _IntrinsicData to external sql in lightswitch.

I got same question here [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754989/change-lightswitch-internal-database-to-external). But not getting proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to force Lightswitch to use another membership database you have to configure this in the web.config file of your Lightswitch server project.

[Customizing LightSwitch User Management by Matt Thalman](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthalman/archive/2013/06/25/customizing-lightswitch-user-management.aspx)